Java application freezes when starting from another java application
I have created Java desktop application with some buttons that will just launch different Java applications and scripts. I have one application that is starting fine, but freezes.
App queue increases
When I close the desktop application then the frozen application start working fine and continue loading data.
I´m not sure what could cause application to freeze. Is there a way to start applications as new instance without having any connections to the main desktop tool application?
I did test threading like new Thread(() ->
But, it gave same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Solved:
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
try {
    String filePath = userprofile+"\\OneDrive\\Tools\\pricedash.bat";
    String[] startOptions = new String[] {filePath};
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(startOptions).start();
    
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    } 
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ToolsDesktop.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
    });

t.start();
